# Installing Windows Server 2019 on a laptop in VMware 16 Player

Tags: windows, virtualization, laptop

I'm trying to set up a lab in order to practice using Server 2019 or similar, but I've hit a roadblock. I'm unsure if Server can even run on a laptop machine via a virtualized environment, specifically VMware 16 Player. I don't wan't to go through the hassle of cloud services or buying a dedicated desktop to play around with, although that might be the better option.

Can anyone help me out with information about configuring VMware to play nicely with Server or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Server 2019 as a guest OS is supported by all recent VMware products, including VMware Workstation Player (the free version of VMware Workstation Pro).

The capabilities of Workstation Player and Workstation Pro are basically the same with regard to host and guest OS support.

You can find all compatibility info here: https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Server ISO and make sure you either can use the trial, or have a license.

Open (run) VMware Player.

In the VMware Player Menu, select File, New Machine.

There are a number of selections and the answers are fairly clear.

You need to select the ISO file you downloaded. Make a Virtual Machine folder (Host system) and put the ISO there. Then select this ISO to make the machine.   Screen shot here.

Note: I am using VMware Workstation but the Player screens are very similar. Just map the instructions to the screen you have.

[image: VMware screen to pick ISO]

Once you have established this, there are settings for CPU and Memory.  Start with 4 GB for the machine and 1 CPU with 2 cores. Do not overpower the machine with resources.

There is a setting for how much disk. Provide 100 GB of disk space for the machine. I always make ONE machine file. The default is for 2 GB segments. I just ONE segment and I do NOT allocate all the space. So the file will grow and sometimes shrink.

These are the main settings. Once you have made the machine and are ready to power on, starting the server for the first time will install it and you can establish a log in.

I am working in a VMware (Workstation) VM right now.

Make sure you have a backup of the ISO file as you can always simply recreate the machine if you wish to make significant changes.